LinkedIn login stuck after entering credentials
I have integrated linkedin oath login within my angular app and the login is working perfect on localhost but when I deploy the localhost to server and try to login with linkedIn after entering my login credentials the login page doesn't do anything (complete the login) and loader on top starts running continously until I have to click the cancel button which redirects me back to my website.
Here is the authorization link I am using:
https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/authorization?response_type=code&client_id=${linkedin_id}&redirect_uri=${linkedin_redirect_url}&state=${this.generateRandomState()}&scope=openid%20profile%20email
I have matched the redirect url on the developer portal with the one provided in the link and both are same
